# Replacing a bs4 element with a string

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have a HTML document, where I want to add HTML anchor link tags so that I can easily go to a certain part of a webpage.

The first step is to find all divs that need to replaced. Secondly, an anchor link tag needs to be added, based on the text that is within the `div`. My code looks as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
path= "/text.html"

with open(path) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "tussenkop"})
    
for div in mydivs:
    if "Artikel" in div.getText():
        string = div.getText().split()[1]
        div_id = f"""<a id="{string}"></a>{div}"""
        full =f"{div_id}{div}"
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(full, 'html.parser')
        div = html_soup
```

A div looks as follows:

`<p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 7.37 text text text</strong></p>`

After adding the anchor tag it becomes:

```
<a id="7.37"></a><p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 10.6 Inwerkingtreding</strong></p><p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 7.37 text text text</strong></p>
```

But the problem is, `div` is not replaced by the new `div`. How should I correct this? Or is there another way to insert an anchor tag?

Comment: You can't assign to an list iterator (in this case `div`) in a loop and expect the list to be updated when you exit the loop. Create a new list before the loop, `new_div` and then replace `div = html_soup` with `new_div.append(html_soup)`. Also don't call a variable `string`, it's a keyword in Python and some other languages (which is why it's highlighted in red in your post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your expected output to look like, but BeautifulSoup has methods to create new tags and attributes, and insert them into the soup object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = '<p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 7.37 text text text</strong>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
print('soup before: ', soup)

mydivs = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "tussenkop"})
    
for div in mydivs:
    if "Artikel" in div.getText():
        a_string = div.getText().split()[1]
        new_tag = soup.new_tag("a")
        new_tag['id'] = f'{a_string}'
        div.insert_before(new_tag)
        
print('soup after: ', soup)
```

**Output:**

```
soup before:  <p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 7.37 text text text</strong></p>
soup after:  <a id="7.37"></a><p class="tussenkop"><strong class="tussenkop_vet">ArtikelÂ 7.37 text text text</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Creating new tags was the answer, learned something new  :)